# AJAX Refresh Div Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('points.txt', function(data){
            $('#show').html(data);
        },1000);
    });
});
</script>

<div id="show"></div>
```

I have the above script running, and in points.txt there's a number which keeps changing.

It's suppose to refresh the div every second.

Now, for some reason, the script ain't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#IndentingCode` helps you a lot to understand the issues. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second param of timing function is not given to the `setInterval`, and not the `get`. Also I guess your request is getting cached. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get('points.txt?' + (new Date).getTime(), function(data){
      $('#show').html(data);
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

Or tell the AJAX, not to cache data:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
});
```

Comment: So what you're saying is my script should work if cache is disabled?

Comment: @HackedFiles Just a second before you already requested the `points.txt` file. So what happens is, `cache` is by default `true`. So the browser takes it from the cache, instead of re-requesting from the server.

Comment: @HackedFiles Also, you have an error in your `setInterval`. Check it out. You are not passing the parameter of `1000` to setInterval, but you are doing it for the `$.get`.

Comment: Will try it out in 30 minutes. The boss is calling me. Will keep you updated!

Comment: Hey, I tried but my freehost server is giving up on me. Google Chrome keeps timing out. Gotta move to a paid host soon. Thanks for helping anyway, I will try the script on my paid server.

Comment: @HackedFiles Lemme tell you, free servers do not take up much load. Please try this with localhost.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is incorrect formatting of your code. Parameter 1000 is added as third parameter to `get` function. Instead it should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('points.txt', function(data){
            $('#show').html(data);
        });
    },1000);
});
```